# How to make parent div width shrink to wrap exactly the child imgs?

Tags: html, css, center

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zxJbV/

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:left">
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
</div>
```

There may be many <img>s and newlines. The parent div always expand to the 100% width and can't wrap the images exactly.
The result I got now(with spacing on the right):
[image]
The result I want is like:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Your fiddle does exactly what you want… correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing this with CSS alone. You'll have to write a bunch media queries to suit every width the container will have - depending on how many items/columns there are in your container.

That being said, I once wrote some LESS code which generates the media queries.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/EBncj/6/) or [CODEPEN (Supports LESS)](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/CizGK)

**Here's how to take advantage of LESS to set up the media queries:**

Set up an iteration mixin like this: (You can paste this code into http://less2css.org)

```
@item-width:100px;
@item-height:100px;
@margin: 5px;
@min-cols:2;
@max-cols:12; //set an upper limit of how may columns you want to write the media queries for


.loopingClass (@index-width) when (@index-width <= @item-width * @max-cols) {
    @media (min-width:@index-width) {
        #content{
            width: @index-width;
        }
    }

    .loopingClass(@index-width + @item-width);
}

.loopingClass (@item-width * @min-cols);
```

The above mixin will spit out a series of media queries in the form:

```
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  #content {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #content {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  #content {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
...
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #content {
    width: 1200px;
  }
}
```

So with a simple markup like:

```
<ul id="content">
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    ...
    <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

With remaining CSS (LESS):

```
 #content {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: @min-cols * @item-width;
    max-width: @max-cols * @item-width;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    background: aqua;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    height: @item-height - 2 *@margin;
    width: @item-width - 2*@margin;
    margin:@margin;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

... you get the desired result.

### ...and it's super easy to customize the layout:

All I need to do is change the variables that I used in the LESS mixin according to my needs - I get the exact layout that I'm after.

So let's say I have items 300px X 100px with a minimum of 2 columns and max 6 columns and a margin of 15px - I just modify the variables like so:

```
@item-width:300px;
@item-height:100px;
@margin: 15px;
@min-cols:2;
@max-cols:6;
```

### ...and voila, I get this [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/skHbI)

Comment: The result looks exactly the same as what I want. I'll have a try, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, normalise your css.

Second, `display: inline-block;` on the images, and `display: block;` on the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/zxJbV/7/

Comment: I didn't see any differences... My problem is that there is always spacing on the right because images get liine-breaks...

Comment: My fiddle looks exactly like the image you posted with the desired result. However, to remove spaces between images, you have a few options: [manually remove them](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/zxJbV/48/) or [do it with javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/zxJbV/49/).

Comment: I don't think your fiddle looks exactly like the image I posted. If you resize the result area, you can see that there's blank area between the right border and images.

Comment: For thee spaces between the images, there's actually a trick to do that. Just add "font-size:0px;" for the container.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem, try this code

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;width:70px;padding:5px;">
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
<img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
</div>
```

The above code contains 1 image per line because i have set the width to 70px, depending on the number of image you want per line please set the width, for example 3 images per line (3x60px = 180px + 10px for the padding). Hope it works. Have a nice day.

Comment: I don't want to set a fixed width for container.

Answer (score 0):

A little jQuery will help you:

`Javascript`:

```
var IMG_WIDTH = 60; // Define your minimum image width here.
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // $('#debug').html($('.container').width());
        var width = $('.container').width();
        if (width % IMG_WIDTH != 0) {
            $('.container img').css({
                width: width / Math.floor(width / 60),
                height: width / Math.floor(width / 60)
            });
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

`CSS`:

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

.

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KBULf/1/)</kbd>

### Non-jQuery solution

```
var IMG_WIDTH = 60;
window.onresize = function() {
    var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
    if (width % IMG_WIDTH != 0) {
        var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll('#container img');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgElements, function(el, i){
            el.style.width = width / Math.floor(width / 60) + 'px';
            el.style.height = width / Math.floor(width / 60) + 'px';
        });
    }
};
window.onresize();
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo no jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt9TS/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using flexbox and not suffer that much. The code will look like this:

index.html

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:left">
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    <img src="" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
</div>
```

main.css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container img {
  flex: 1; 
}
```

working pen: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0100;

Hope helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  background-color:yellow!important;
}

 .main div {
 
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main div.nogrow{
  flex-grow: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main" >
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:coral;">dsfddsfdfA</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightblue;">dfdfdfdB</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:khaki;">dfdfdf d fd fdC</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:pink;">Ddssd sdf sdf</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightgrey;"> df df df ddf dfE</div>
  <div class="nogrow" style="background-color:lightgreen;"> dfd fd df dfdF</div>
</div>
```

@TrungDQ thanks for your support.  I have a similar issue, but width is dynamic, and Do not want empty spaces at the right side. Could you kindly take a look? https://jsfiddle.net/phyle5/07pwdy12/  Please resize and see.